# How to publish Redoc to gh-pages

Tags: redoc

I have completed the creation of docs using redoc along with all formatting. Now I want to publish it on github pages.

There is a way where i can generate the static html pages using below command -

```
npx redoc-cli bundle demo/openapi.yaml
```

But one problem with this approach is - it doesn't preserve the formatting.

Is there any way we can publish the documentation with all formatting on gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "formatting".

In order to publish anything on github pages you have to have static files. Right?

Solution that worked for me.

Grab a html template from doc page [redoc/quickstart/html/](https://redoc.ly/docs/redoc/quickstart/html/)
On that page you have everything you need except for json api doc

You can convert your yaml api definition to json  with `bundle` command. Just run this command in the directory with `<your_api_definition>.yaml`, e.g. my command:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/spec redocly/openapi-cli bundle  --output openapi --ext json openapi.yaml
```

After this you should get yourself a json api definition — `openapi.json`
Now add these two files to your repository and configure github pages.
That is it.

Here is my working variant https://slash3b.me/3cc7e72996eb2b9ef.github.io/index.html

Comment: Thanks but just wanted to share, you can provide the yaml file as well in the static html to let it work.